# Table Joining Issues

Tags: sql, oracle

I have difficulties joining the tables below for the desired query as stated.

Theatre (Theatre#, Name, Address, MainTel);

Production (P#, Title, ProductionDirector, PlayAuthor);

Performance (Per#, P#, Theatre#, pDate, pHour, pMinute, Comments);

Client (Client#, Title, Name, Street, Town, County, telNo, e-mail);

Ticket Purchase (Purchase#, Client#, Per#, PaymentMethod, DeliveryMethod, TotalAmount)

**Required Query**

The theater name (for each theater) and the names of clients who have the highest spending in that theater

```
SELECT T.NAME, C.NAME, SUM(TOTALAMOUNT)
FROM   TICKETPURCHASE TP,
       THEATRE T,
       CLIENT C,
       PERFORMANCE PER
WHERE  TOTALAMOUNT = (SELECT MAX (TOTALAMOUNT)
                      FROM   TICKETPURCHASE TP2,
                             THEATRE T2,
                             PERFORMANCE PER2,
                             CLIENT C2,
                             PRODUCTION P2
                      WHERE  T2.NAME = T.NAME
                      AND    T2.THEATRE# = PER2.THEATRE#
                      AND    TP2.CLIENT# = C2.CLIENT#
                      AND    TP2.PER# =PER2.PER#
                      AND    PER2.P# = P2.P# )
AND    C.CLIENT# = TP.CLIENT#
AND    T.THEATRE# = PER.THEATRE#
AND    TP.PER# = PER.PER#
AND    PER.P# = P.P#
GROUP BY T.NAME, C.NAME, TOTALAMOUNT
```

Comment: Clean up and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can do it all in a single query if you aggregate by the primary keys for the theatre and the client to get the total spent and then rank the spending in the `ORDER BY` clause and use the row limiting clause to get the first ranked values:

```sql
SELECT MAX(T.NAME) AS theatre_name,
       MAX(C.NAME) AS client_name,
       SUM(TP.TOTALAMOUNT) AS amount_spent
FROM   TICKETPURCHASE TP
       INNER JOIN PERFORMANCE PER
       ON (TP.PER# = PER.PER#)
       INNER JOIN THEATRE T
       ON (T.THEATRE# = PER.THEATRE#)
       INNER JOIN CLIENT C
       ON (C.CLIENT# = TP.CLIENT#)
GROUP BY
       T.THEATRE#,
       C.CLIENT#
ORDER BY
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         PARTITION BY T.THEATRE#
         ORDER BY SUM(TP.TOTALAMOUNT) DESC
       )
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

In earlier versions, you can use the same technique and filter in an outer query:

```sql
SELECT theatre_name,
       client_name,
       amount_spent
FROM   (
  SELECT MAX(T.NAME) AS theatre_name,
         MAX(C.NAME) AS client_name,
         SUM(TP.TOTALAMOUNT) AS amount_spent,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY T.THEATRE#
           ORDER BY SUM(TP.TOTALAMOUNT) DESC
         ) As rnk
  FROM   TICKETPURCHASE TP
         INNER JOIN PERFORMANCE PER
         ON (TP.PER# = PER.PER#)
         INNER JOIN THEATRE T
         ON (T.THEATRE# = PER.THEATRE#)
         INNER JOIN CLIENT C
         ON (C.CLIENT# = TP.CLIENT#)
  GROUP BY
         T.THEATRE#,
         C.CLIENT#
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```